# Firebird sql transaction count is very high?

Tags: firebird

My firebird SQL database got corrupted recently, and I'm not sure why.

The error I got when it occurred was:

> 'Error while executing SQL statement:\n- SQLCODE: -902\n- database
>   file appears corrupt (/home/firebird/my_db.fdb)\n- wrong page type\n-
>   page 305659 is of wrong type (expected 7, found 109)\n- internal
>   Firebird consistency check (error during savepoint backout (290),
>   file: exe.cpp line: 4056)', -902, 335544335)

The statement executed before the error was an insert or update, but I do a lot of those (in small batches) before doing a commit that I make sure to do each time.

After fixing it with gfix, I noticed that the transaction count (and Generation) values got reset down. I assume this normal, but I'd like to know if it's normal to have these numbers increase all the time.

I also guess not having a sweep interval in the corrupted version is part of the problem?

Here are fbstat output for the *corrupted* file, and below for the *fixed* file.

```
root@ubuntu:~# fbstat -h /home/firebird/my_db.fdb_corrupted

Database "/home/firebird/my_db.fdb_corrupted"
Database header page information:
        Flags                   0
        Checksum                12345
        Generation              475060
        Page size               4096
        ODS version             11.2
        Oldest transaction      474915
        Oldest active           474954
        Oldest snapshot         474954
        Next transaction        474956
        Bumped transaction      1
        Sequence number         0
        Next attachment ID      3656
        Implementation ID       24
        Shadow count            0
        Page buffers            0
        Next header page        0
        Database dialect        3
        Creation date           Apr 30, 2018 11:50:10
        Attributes              force write

    Variable header data:
        *END*

root@ubuntu:~# fbstat -h /home/firebird/my_db.fdb_fixed

Database "/home/firebird/my_db.fdb_corrupted_fixed"
Database header page information:
        Flags                   0
        Checksum                12345
        Generation              45
        Page size               4096
        ODS version             11.2
        Oldest transaction      32
        Oldest active           33
        Oldest snapshot         33
        Next transaction        36
        Bumped transaction      1
        Sequence number         0
        Next attachment ID      3
        Implementation ID       24
        Shadow count            0
        Page buffers            0
        Next header page        0
        Database dialect        3
        Creation date           May 11, 2018 17:42:15
        Attributes              force write

    Variable header data:
        Sweep interval:         20000
        *END*
```

**Actual question**: is there a potential link between the corruption of the database and the high numbers in the statistics above?

I read [the manual](https://www.firebirdsql.org/manual/gstat-example-header.html) but I doubt the corruption is related. Just need to make sure since I don't understand why these high numbers went back down after using `gfix` on the corrupted file.

I also don't understand why there is no sweep interval showing for the corrupted file.

Perhaps I shouldn't ask on StackOverflow since it's not directly programming related? Is there a better place for this kind of question?

Comment: The gstat output suggests that you did not only use gfix, but also backed up and restored the database using gbak. Is that correct?

Comment: Ah, yes that is correct.

Comment: `since it's not directly programming related?` Correct. The officially proper avenue would be http://ServerFault.com - however whether there are a lot of people versed in Firebird I am not sure :-D

Comment: Just compare with the activity you can see here: https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/firebird

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error indicates a corruption of the database on a storage level. This cannot be caused by the transaction count. The error

> wrong page type\n- page 305659 is of wrong type (expected 7, found 109)

Means that Firebird expected to read page of type 7 (index B-tree page), but got type 109 (which is not a known page type). How this problem came about is hard to say for sure, but causes can be things like bugs in Firebird, power interruptions or Firebird process killed during write of that page (or another page that incorrectly pointed to an allocated but unused page), manual tampering with the database file, bad sectors on the hard drive, etc.

Your transaction account is not "very high". The transaction number will increment with each transaction started, until you hit the maximum (2<sup>31</sup> - 1 in Firebird 2.5 and earlier, or 2<sup>48</sup> in Firebird 3 and higher), at which point you need to backup and restore the database to reset the transaction count. The transaction number of 474956 is between 2<sup>18</sup> and 2<sup>19</sup>, in other words there was enough transaction space left.

Similarly the *Generation* indicates the number of times the header page (first page of the database file) has been rewritten. This happens at least once for each transaction start, and for some other changes.

The reason that the transaction count was reset, is because you backed up and restored the database using `gbak`. Gbak creates a logical backup of the database (the structure and data, but not the physical layout of datapages), and when you restore it, a new database will be created and the structure and data will be written in 2 or more transactions (depending on config options of gbak a single transaction will be used for all data, or a transaction per table).

The sweep interval was set because on initial creation of the database it wasn't, which implies the default value of 20000, and now on restore it was set explicitly.

Comment: Thank you very much! 
I was under the impression that I did not need to explicitly set a sweep interval as there was a default upon DB creation.
According to [gfix-housekeeping](https://www.firebirdsql.org/pdfmanual/html/gfix-housekeeping.html)
since I do a lot of rollbacked transactions, and I also did generate a lot of exceptions due to primary key uniqueness violations for example, I probably generated a lot of garbage that never got cleared out. Could be related to the corruption? I'll keep an eye out.
Thanks for JDBC by the way.

Comment: @Hernn0 Sweep interval is 20000 by default, on creation of a new database it is not explicitly set, but on backup that value is stored (even if derived from the default), so on restore the setting gets set explicitly. As I said, it is hard to guess as to a cause, and the number of rollbacks or exceptions should not influence that (unless of course, specifically those actions trigger a bug, but then you would have corruptions all the time).